# Do not show time but only date in my Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

[Example of wrong figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkEPw.png)

Need help~! I have plotted a figure for my data. But when I check the figure, the x-axis shows time, but I do not want to show the specific time but only the month (for example, I only wish to show like: 2018-01, 2018-02, but not like 2018-01-01 00:00:00). I do not know what is wrong about my code and it does not show in my terminal run result. So confused, please if someone provides some suggestion.
Many thanks. Code is below

```
data = pd.read_csv('micro_null_data.csv')

clean1_data = pd.value_counts(data['SAMPLE_NAME'])


Zone2 = data.loc[data['SAMPLE_NAME'] =='Zone 2', ['SAMPLED_DATE', 'FORMATTED_ENTRY']]
value_map = {
    'Not Detected': 1,
    'Detected': 0,
}

Zone2_table = pd.crosstab(pd.to_datetime(Zone2['SAMPLED_DATE']), Zone2['FORMATTED_ENTRY'])
Zone2_table.drop(Zone2_table.index[474], inplace=True)
print(Zone2_table)

Zone2_by_mongth = Zone2_table.resample('M').sum()
print(Zone2_by_mongth)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.style.use('seaborn')
Zone2_by_mongth.plot.bar()

plt.title('Zone 2')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Comment: look up how to set the xtick formating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `Zone2_table` line code to as below. Just this line.

```
Zone2_table = pd.crosstab(pd.to_datetime(Zone2['SAMPLED_DATE']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m'), Zone2['FORMATTED_ENTRY'])
```

Comment: If the answer helped you, consider Up-Voting & accepting the answer.

Comment: Just did, thanks Moys. Sorry for the delay, I am still a beginner both in stackoverflow and data science. Thanks for help

Comment: No problem. I was once there & i can totally imagine your situation :-)